# What's faster EF 4.1 Code First or EF 4.0 Model First?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-model-first

Are there any performance benefits in either of the methods?

Comment: what kind of "speed" do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. EF 4.1 is just wrapper around EF 4.0 so there is no difference - at least no difference which would make sense to measure.